# Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key (gksudo:2984): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

Tags: software-installation, 17.04

when i run tuxcut,i see this message 
i try this command and not run tuxcut

```
user@server:~$ xhost +localhost
su -
Defaults env_keep=DISPLAY
xhost +localhost &
xhost +SI:localuser:root &
gksudo "lxterminal --command "nano /etc/default/grub""
```

how i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `su` without the dash.  That will keep the XAUTHORITY environment variable intact.